# use-default-template configuration tag does not work

Tags: templates, default, liferay

I've created simple "Hello world" portlet and just added

```
<use-default-template>true</use-default-template>
```

to the portlet section of liferay-portlet.xml file.

Portlet stopped to work with the following exception in the log

11:29:03,973 ERROR [PortletLocalServiceImpl:656] com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.DocumentException: Error on line 13 of document  : The content of element type "portlet" must match "(portlet-name,icon?,............ and so on

The name of my tag is present here.

Why is this? Is this tag obsolete or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order of the tags on the liferay-portlet.xml. You should put the tags on the right order following the "spec" ([DTD](http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_0_0.dtd)).

Comment: Eclipse actually checks it (at least my Helios SR1 with Liferay IDE 1.3.1.v201108310601). If you open it with the XML editor you should get the same error regarding the order. If you are not getting it, maybe you cannot reach the DTD's URL (are you behind a proxy?).

Comment: It looks like DTD check is working in general. For example, it gives me other errors, and shows correct coding proposals for this specific XML. But not about order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes problem with DTD order only.

You can can see some good articles of liferay portal.

http://www.exceptionhandle.com/portal/category/portals-2