# runtime added portlets do not rendered when parent portlet has use-default-template value true

Tags: java, spring, liferay, liferay-6

I am working on a portlet which accepts the portlet ids and renders those portlets. So, basically you can think of something like a container portlet.

When the container portlet has a value `<use-default-template>false</use-default-template>` in `liferay-portlet.xml`, everything works fine. It is able to render the portlet via tag `<liferay-portlet:runtime portletName="1_WAR_sampleportlet" />`

But, if I make the entry `<use-default-template>true</use-default-template>` for the container portlet (or just remove the tag, as default is `true`), it simply ignore the `<liferay-portlet:runtime />` tag and shows nothing.

The other information are

- Liferay version : liferay 6.2 EE
- Java version : Java 7
- Portlet Type : Spring MVC portlet

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below links, as this question is already answered earlier in stackoverflow.

[use-default-template configuration tag does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953174/use-default-template-configuration-tag-does-not-work)

Also, not that if you disable "use-default-template" then Liferay is doing exactly what you requested: It does not display any default controls and only shows the content created by the portlet's render() method.

So if you need to have a configuration link (or a remove button or any other control present in the default template), your portlet has to render it on its own.

Comment: Hi Neeraj, the link is not an answer of my question, as per documentation, it should at least render the portlet content. But it is not rendering that! the <liferay-portlet:runtime /> is a body of the container portlet and it must be rendered. (with or without portlet.vm rendering).

Comment: <use-default-template> value has to be false only. If it is set to true, it won't read liferay-portlet:runtime tag. It will only render default components and not your customize one.